# How To map a CSV field with @JoinColumn property (Entity) in FlatFileItemReader - Spring Batch

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-batch

I'm using the spring batch job to insert data into a MySql Table from a CSV file.
one of the Entity properties is a JoinColumn generated using @ManyToOne 
My problem is the field on the CSV file for the ManyToOne property is considered as the Entity @ID field and not mapped with the JoinColumn which generate an Error,

```
@Entity
public class User {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer id;
private String name;
private String dept;
private Integer salary;
private Date  endDate;
private Date time;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "carId", referencedColumnName = "id",   foreignKey=@ForeignKey(name = "FK_Car_User"))
private Car car;
.....
```

The Csv file :

```
car_id,name1,dept1,salary1,endDate
1,Peter,001,12000,1970-07-28
2,Sam,002,13000,1970-07-28
1,Ryan,003,10000,1970-07-28
```

The LineMapper

```
    lineTokenizer.setDelimiter(",");
    lineTokenizer.setStrict(false);
    lineTokenizer.setNames(new String[]{"carId", "name2", "dept2", "salary2","endDate"});

    Map<Class<?>, PropertyEditor> editors = new HashMap<>();
    CustomDateEditor dateEditor = new CustomDateEditor(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"), true);
    editors.put(Date.class, dateEditor);

    BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<User> fieldSetMapper = new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<>();
    fieldSetMapper.setTargetType(User.class);
    fieldSetMapper.setCustomEditors(editors);

    defaultLineMapper.setLineTokenizer(lineTokenizer);
    defaultLineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(fieldSetMapper);
```

the Error is :

```
Data Saved for Users: [User{id=1, name='Peter', dept='Technology', salary=12000}, User{id=2, 
name='Sam', dept='Operations', salary=13000}, User{id=1, name='Ryan', dept='Accounts', 
salary=10000}]
2019-10-05 18:49:56.308  WARN 8984 --- [nio-8081-exec-4] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : 
SQL Error: 23502, SQLState: 23502
2019-10-05 18:49:56.308 ERROR 8984 --- [nio-8081-exec-4] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : 
NULL not allowed for column "CAR_ID"; SQL statement:
insert into user (id, car_id, dept, end_date, name, salary, time) values (null, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) 
[23502-197]
```

Thanks for your suggestions

Comment: i changed the DistenceLimte(0) to match exactly the properties names in the entity, but i got an error related to the @ManyToOne join column                               
   ------------------------------------------                                                                                                                       
 Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'carId' of bean class [com.techprimers.springbatchexample1.model.User]: Bean property 'carId' is not writable or has an invalid setter m

Comment: according to the error, you need a setter for `carId`

Answer (score 0):

The solution consists of :
1- Create a customized FieldSetMapper class instead of using BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper.
2- autowiring an object CarService (To fetch the Car from the repository) in the FieldSetMapper Customized Class 
3- in the Implementation of mapFieldSet(FieldSet fs) method set the @ManyToOne property as following 
user.setCar(carService.getCarById(fieldSet.readString("carId")));